# iScrollView Doesn't Work with Dyanmic ListView in jQMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, uiscrollview

i have a dynamic listview in jquery mobile 1.4 in Cordova and i am using iscrollview. If the listview isn't dynamic then scroll works fine. However, with dynamic it's not working. I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8zyL87b/);

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    var htmls = '<ul data-role="listview">';
    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        htmls +='<li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>';
    }
     htmls +='</ul>';
     $(".example-wrapper").append(htmls);
     $("ul", $('#index')).listview();
    $(".example-wrapper").iscrollview("refresh");
});
```

Notice that the listview doesn't exist in the DOM (in html). So it means its constructed dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not working because when you append htmls to the example-wrapper, iScroll has already generated its inner scroll elements. So try this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    var htmls = '<ul data-role="listview">';
    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        htmls +='<li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>';
    }
     htmls +='</ul>';
     $(".example-wrapper .iscroll-content").append(htmls);
     $("ul", $('#index')).listview();
    $(".example-wrapper").iscrollview("refresh");
});
```

I forked your Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rLk1cmkx/)

Comment: i should have noticed that first :P. Any how thanks